# Print common lines in two files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two files:

```
file1 = "He is a man\n He likes the football\n The tennis is a popular game\n His work is very interessing \n He comes from Rome\n"

file2 = "is a man/[VF]\n popular game/[Af]\n the football/[DN]"
```

What I want to do: if one line in file2(without the annotation) is present in file1, then I want to replace this line in file1, but with the annotation (for instance /[Af).

so my result should be like this:

```
file1 = "He is a man[VF]\n He likes the football[DN]\n The tennis is a popular game[Af]\n His work is very interessing \n He comes from Rome\n"
```

I tried something like this:

```
delimiter = '/'

    for line in file2.splitlines():
        if delimiter in line:
            newline = line.strip()
            tag = line[line.index(delimiter):-1].strip()
            tok = line[1:line.index(delimiter)].strip()
            for l in file1.splitlines():
                print l.replace(tok, newline)
```

but the problem is the over repetition in the result

Comment: Should those phrases be replaced whereever they occur, or only in the corresponding line? E.g., "the football" was replaced only once; was this on purpose?

Comment: I am struggling to really see any rhyme or reason with regards of how you are imagining how those two strings will produce that output.

Comment: No, the phrases should be replaced whereever they occur, the second "the football" should also be replaced.I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is hard to understand what you want to do, only general course here: if your second file is not too large to fit into memory, just create a dictionary `d` where keys are source lines and values are lines you want to replace. After that

```
result = [d.get(line,line) for line in file1]
```

will do the trick. It is not the fastest way, but reasonable enough to use. Dictionaries in python search its keys with clever math, so it is fast.

Comment: What I want to do: if one line in file2(without the annotation) is present in file1, then I want to replace this line in file1, but with the annotation (for instance /[Af).

Comment: No difference. It will be `[d.get(line,line)+annotation for line in file1]`